# using random forest for missing data imputation in categorical variables ( in R)

Tags: r, random-forest, missing-data, data-imputation

I have following type of **associated** data. The following example step to generate associated variable. **p** number of variables and **n** is number of observations.

```
p = 500
n = 200
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol = 500, nrow = 200)

for (i in 1:p){
if(i ==1){
     fs <- sample (c("AA", "AB", "AB", "BB"), n, replace=TRUE) 
     mat[,i] <- fs 
     fs1 <- fs 
     } 
rechr <- sample(1:n, 1)
fs1[rechr] <- sample (c("AA", "AB", "AB", "BB"), 1)
mat[,i] <- fs1 
}

dim(mat)
mat[1:10,1:20]
```

The above data is complete, but in real dataset I have missing values (which are randomly distributed within each variables).

I would like to predict them using random forest (or any other appropriate algorithms). Let's randomly put 10% missing values (the approximate number of variables) to the above data.

```
rowind <- sample(1:n, 20)
colind <- sample(1:p, 20)

for (i in 1:length(rowind)){
                mat[rowind[i],colind[i]] <- NA
}
mat[1:20,1:10]
```

How can do this and **what issues** I need to think up in doing so - considering **categorical variables**, number of observations and variables ?

**Edit:**
As all variables are correlated and none are response (but can serve as response) while prediction. for example mat[,1] missing value prediction can be based on rest of variables, mat[,2] prediction can be based on prediction of rest of variables. So the objective here is prediction all missing values in all variables (all of them are categorical).

**Edit 2**

I am interested in [multiple imputation](http://support.sas.com/rnd/app/papers/multipleimputation.pdf) of this data so that I can perform other analysis that requires complete dataset without missing value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looks like you are interested in multiple imputations. See this [link](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/multiple-imputation-of-categorical-variables/) on ways you can impute / handle categorical data.  The link discuss on [details](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/113-30.pdf) and how to do this in SAS.

The R package `mice` can handle categorical data for univariate cases using logistic regression and discriminant function analysis (see the [link](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/)). If you use SAS `proc mi` is way to go [[see link]](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/113-30.pdf).

Edit:

You can use the function `rfunsuper` used in my answer for the [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/107530/using-cluster-information-in-multiple-imputation/108115#108115).

```
p = 500
n = 200
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol = 500, nrow = 200)

for (i in 1:p){
if(i ==1){
     fs <- sample (c("AA", "AB", "AB", "BB"), n, replace=TRUE) 
     mat[,i] <- fs 
     fs1 <- fs 
     } 
rechr <- sample(1:n, 1)
fs1[rechr] <- sample (c("AA", "AB", "AB", "BB"), 1)
mat[,i] <- fs1 
}

dim(mat)

rowind <- sample(1:n, 20)
colind <- sample(1:p, 20)

for (i in 1:length(rowind)){
                mat[rowind[i],colind[i]] <- NA
}
mat[1:20,1:10]

out1 <- rfunsuper (data.frame(mat), iter=5, ntree=100)
diff.rel = 1.555556 / 50587.33 = 3.07499e-05 
diff.rel = 0.1111111 / 50590.67 = 2.196277e-06 

Call:
 randomForest(x = x.roughfixed, ntree = ntree) 
               Type of random forest: unsupervised
                     Number of trees: 100
No. of variables tried at each split: 22
```

Answer (score 4):

dfife's answer is good though it may be informative to re-read Breiman's description of how random forests can handle missing values in the training data while trying to predict a variable without missing values:
[http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#missing1](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#missing1)

Another approach I've had good luck with to predict or get importance scores from data sets with missing values *with out imputing* is three way splitting which splits the missing value onto a third branch at each node. This is particularly useful if the fact something is NA may actually be informative (ie in a survey where a question being left blank may be significant).

This method originates (to my knowledge) in Timo Erkkila's rf-ace: https://code.google.com/p/rf-ace/ and can also be found in my implementation, CloudForest: https://github.com/ryanbressler/CloudForest.

rf-ace has a (difficult to build) r-package, cloudforest doesn't yet but is faster and more memory efficient and can also handle missing values via a bias correction without three way splitting or imputation as in some variants of CART.

If you have missing values in the thing you are trying to predict you may want to look into methods for semi supervised learning. If you want an unsupervised method for imputing missing values while you aren't trying to predict thing you could start with nearest neighbor imputation or impute to the variable mean or mode (as Breiman suggests to initialize his method for RF imputation).

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways of doing it that depends on what you're trying to do. You can impute the missing values using the **proximity matrix** (the `rfImpute` function in the `randomForest` package).

If you're only interested in **computing variable importance**, you can use the `cforest` function in the `party` package then compute variable importance via the `varimp()` function. This approach is based on [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-012-9349-1#page-1), which suggests a very clever way of **bypassing** the missing data (and handling it in an elegant way) in order to compute variable importance.

Comment: I am interested in imputing - the first point you made. Double checking if this works for categorical variables - what would be y and x variables ?

Comment: You set up the rfImpute exactly as you do for the randomForest part. See ?rfImpute for an example using the Iris data. [iris.imputed <- rfImpute(Species ~ ., iris.na); iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris.imputed)]

Comment: my question here is : None of the above variables are y variables, but each can be used as y, but the problem here is that every variables have at least NA making them unsuitable for using `rfImpute`

Comment: You mentioned you were trying to predict...what are you trying to predict if there's no y? What is the end result? Perhaps a little more context would help.

Comment: please see my recent edits.

Comment: I'm still not quite able to see the purpose. Are you trying to do an unsupervised clustering the data? (That's the only explanation for why you wouldn't have a dv that I can think of). Maybe a bit more explanation on the substantive question you're trying to address (e.g., "each of the variables are binary responses to a political questionnaire and we're trying to segregate people into clusters based on their responses.")

Comment: The purpose is to complete the data so that i can do other analysis that requires complete data. one thing I can simply do is calculate mode and replace missing value with mode (most frequent value) but I think more powerful approaches do exist and want to take advantage of them.

Comment: You might want to try this approach: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49270/imputation-with-random-forests. It seems reasonable (first iteration=median imputation, second iteration = impute with proximity, repeat).