# using cluster information in multiple imputation

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

i need to impute a dataset all categorical variables before doing analysis. I can just simply **impute** with mode of all data or a variable.

I belief that better option will be to **classify** the subjects (observations) using some short of **clustering algorithm** and then use this information to **impute** the data. The following is small data (though the real data is really big) and the idea.

```
md <- data.frame(V1 = c("AA", "AA", "AA", NA, "AB"), V2 = c("AB", "AB", "BB", "BB", "BB"), V3 = c("BB", NA, "BB", "BB", "BB"), V4 = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA"), 
 V5=c(rep("AB", 5)), V6 = c("BB", "BB", "AB", "AB", NA), V7 = c("AB", "AB", "BB", "BB", "BB"))

 md
    V1 V2   V3 V4 V5   V6   V7
1   AA AB   BB AA   AB   BB AB
2   AA AB <NA> AA   AB   BB AB
3   AA BB   BB AA   AB   AB BB
4 <NA> BB   BB AA   AB   AB BB
5   AB BB   BB AA   AB <NA> BB
```

In visual observation, the sample 1 and 2 are more similar in one cluster while 3,4,5 are in second cluster. The side is hand drawn dendogram (I could not due HC because of missing values).

Now I would like to impute all missing values based on the similarity. For example, missing value in column 1 is most likely to be AA as sample 4 is more similar to 3 than 1, 2, or 5. Similarly the 5 column missing value is BB as the **neighbor** in the cluster is also BB. Similarly column 6 value should be AB as the closest similar has AB. and so on.

[image]

Thus completed data would look like:

[image]

How can we perform this ?

Comment: You're looking to do single rather than multiple imputation? Are you familiar with eg MICE?

Comment: multiple imputation might be good, but I do not know if works for categorical data

Comment: MICE:  multiple imputation by chained equations.  When you have hierarchical data, I think the way it works is that you specify your models at each level.  In your case, you'd probably want multinomial logits to predict the category.  I.e.: pr(category|level, whatever else).  It can be a pain to code, easy to miscode, and computationally intensive, but it's pretty flexible.  And I guess that you'd need to address the uncertainty in your clustering algorithm as well.  It might not be the best choice.

Comment: I agree with @ACD that a MICE package can be used to impute categorical data like yours.  I don't think "hierarchical data" applies here, which simplifies your task.  Still, doing it in R is no simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function is based on the paper "[Imputation of Missing Values for Unsupervised Data  Using the Proximity in Random Forests](http://www.rd.dnc.ac.jp/~tunenori/doc/elml_2013_3_20_50062.pdf)" by Tsunenori Ishioka in eLmL 2013. Please follow the paper for methodological details. Note that this function is applicable for both categorical and numerical data.

```
rfunsuper <- function (x, iter=5, ntree=100){
# three different functions 
#   Return k-neighbor weighted mean for numeric variables or
#   most weighted frequent factor element for factor variables.
KWmean <- function (value, weight, k=10){
    if (missing(weight)){
         w <- rep.int(1, length(value))
    }else if (length(weight) != length(value)){
        stop("'value' and 'weight' must have the same length")
    }
    k <- min(k, length(value))
    if (is.numeric(value)){
        order.weight <- order(weight, decreasing = T)
        ww <- weight[order.weight]
        vv <- value[order.weight]
        ret <- sum(ww[1:k] * vv[1:k]) / sum(ww[1:k])

    }else if(is.factor(value)){ 
        wgt.sum <- tapply(weight, value, sum)
        # most weighted frequent factor element
        ret <- names(subset (wgt.sum, wgt.sum == max(wgt.sum, na.rm=T)))
    }else{
        stop("'value' is neither numeric nor factor")
    }
    return(ret)
}
#   Return relative distance between `x.impute' to `x.org' 
relatImpOrg <- function (x.impute, x.org){    
    #   x.impute: imputed data
    #   x.org: original data
    ncol.x <- length(x.org)
    x.abs.org <-  matrix(abs(as.numeric(unlist(x.org))), ncol=ncol.x)
    max.x <- apply(x.abs.org, 2, max) # for normalization of features size
    # `x.impute' and `x.org' may include factor elements
    if (FALSE){ # available for only numeric
      diff.x <- (x.impute - x.org) / max.x # normalize
      diff.rel <- sum(diff.x^2) / sum((x.org / max.x)^2) 
    }else{
      mat.x.impute <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x.impute)), ncol=ncol.x)
      mat.x.org <- matrix(as.numeric(unlist(x.org)), ncol=ncol.x)
      max.numx <- as.numeric(unlist(max.x))
      diff.x <- sweep((mat.x.impute - mat.x.org), 2, max.numx, FUN="/") 
      size.org <- sweep(mat.x.org, 2, max.numx, FUN="/")
      diff.rel <- sum(diff.x^2) / sum(size.org^2)
    }
    cat ("diff.rel =", sum(diff.x^2), "/", sum(size.org^2), "=", diff.rel, "\n")
    return(diff.rel)
}
#   Impute or revise NA elements using the data proximity.
prox.nafix <- function (na.values, rough.values, x.prox){
#   na.values: data vector that includes NA; unchanged.
#   rough.values: rough data vector to be replaced; NAs cannot include.
#   x.prox: data proximity matrix; each element is positive and <= 1.
    if (length(na.values) != length(rough.values)){
        stop("'na.values' and 'rough.values' must have the same length");
    }else if (length(rough.values) != ncol(x.prox)){
        stop("'rough.values' and 'x.prox' size incorrect");
    }
    # NA imputation ONLY for NA data
    na.list <- which(is.na(na.values))
    if (length(na.list) == 0){
        # no NAs
        return(rough.values)
    }
    replaced.vales <- rough.values
    for (i in 1:length(na.list)){
        j <- na.list[i]
        x.prox[j,j] <- 0 # ignore the weight of the data to be imputed.
        replaced.vales[j] <- KWmean (rough.values, x.prox[,j])
    }
    return(replaced.vales)
}
    require(randomForest)
    x.roughfixed <- na.roughfix(x)
    #For numeric variables, NAs are replaced with column medians. 
    #For factor variables, NAs are replaced with the most frequent levels (breaking ties at random).
    rf.impute <- x
    while (iter){
      x.rf <- randomForest(x.roughfixed, ntree=ntree)
      #randomForest implements Breiman's random forest algorithm
      x.prox <- x.rf$proximity
      #a matrix of proximity measures among the input 
      #(based on the frequency that pairs of data points are in the same terminal nodes).
      for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
        rf.impute[,i] <- prox.nafix(x[,i], x.roughfixed[,i], x.prox)
      }
      diff.rel <- relatImpOrg(rf.impute, x.roughfixed)
      if (diff.rel < 1e-5){
        break
      }else{
        x.roughfixed <- rf.impute
        iter <- iter -1
      }
    }
    print(x.rf)
    return(rf.impute)
}
```

Now let's implement in your situation.

```
library(randomForest)
# your data 
md <- data.frame(V1 = c("AA", "AA", "AA", NA, "AB"), 
      V2 = c("AB", "AB", "BB", "BB", "BB"),
      V3 = c("BB", NA, "BB", "BB", "BB"),
      V4 = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA"), 
     V5=c(rep("AB", 5)),        
    V6 = c("BB", "BB", "AB", "AB", NA),
     V7 = c("AB", "AB", "BB", "BB", "BB"))

rfunsuper (md, iter=5, ntree=100)
```

The imputed output exactly match to your expectations:

```
diff.rel = 0 / 28.11111 = 0 

Call:
 randomForest(x = x.roughfixed, ntree = ntree) 
               Type of random forest: unsupervised
                     Number of trees: 100
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1 AA AB BB AA AB BB AB
2 AA AB BB AA AB BB AB
3 AA BB BB AA AB AB BB
4 AA BB BB AA AB AB BB
5 AB BB BB AA AB AB BB
```