# Imputation Methods for Multiple Variables

Tags: python, missing-data, data-imputation, recurrent-neural-network, pandas

I am training Recurrent Neural Network models (including LSTMs) on a dataset that includes 6-10 variables. Each variable is a properly formatted numerical measurement (ie: length, pressure, temperature, etc). The raw data does not have a measurement of each variable at each timestamp. I have aggregated the raw data into a Pandas Data Frame, so that each row corresponds to a timestamp when at least one variable was recorded, but many rows are missing values for one or more variables.

My first idea was to us KNN methods to impute values, but this method gets weaker with as we reduce the number of variables available to use for finding similar data point clusters. Imputing based on mean/medians seems like a poor idea due to the expected correlated fluctuation of values. I have run models with these rows (times when multiple variables are missing values) dropped, but I would like to see if a model would perform better with these imputed steps (as I assume it would).

${\bf My} \space{} {\bf Question:} $ 
I need to impute values for these cases when missing multiple variable values. Are there imputation methods for similar cases which the Cross Validated Community find stronger than KNN?

Comment: If you don't have all that many missing values, you could also just drop those rows. How many rows do you have? And how many rows have missing values?

Comment: I can adjust my time frames, but most recently was working with a data set with around 1200 rows, about 47% had a raw value for each variable, so about 53% missing values

Comment: Ah, I see. That's too much missing data for the number of rows you have to make dropping feasible.

Comment: I thought so, I appreciate hearing that someone else came to a similar conclusion

Comment: Would getting more data allow you to greatly change the ratio of rows to rows with missing data? Or how much control do you have over the data acquisition?

Comment: data streaming is live, so future data may be more complete (may be less) but the processes being measured are out of my control.

Comment: It looks like missing data is an actual part of your data structure, so you don't want to blindly impute. For each variable that has missing values, add a dummy indicator variable that takes the value 1 if this variable is missing. You can then impute the variable with missing values as you see fit with no loss of information. Also, when you get future data with missing values, your predictions will take into account there were missing values (which may be informative).

Comment: Also, because you have so few variables, you can use random forest imputation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49270/imputation-with-random-forests